# Как выровнять блок по вертикальному центру независимо от размера экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть блок `headings` который хочу размещать по вертикальному центру экрана независимо от размеров экрана и кроссбраузерности ie8+ (flexbox не пойдет), причем с `header` и `footer` прибитыми сверху и снизу соответственно. Сейчас отображается нормально для средних экранов, но на больших - блок подброшен вверх.Как это можно сделать? [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/xdkrxtn1/)

```css
header {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.headings {
  padding: 5% 0 15% 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.headings h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  text-shadow: 0px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0;
}
.headings h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky" id="header">
  <nav>Menu</nav>
</header>
<div class="headings">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <h2>Описание</h2>
  <p><a href="#">телефон</a>
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>&copy; copyright</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, нашел правильное решение [(фидл)](https://jsfiddle.net/xdkrxtn1/5/):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.headings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.headings h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  text-shadow: 0px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0;
}
.headings h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky" id="header">
  <nav>Menu</nav>
</header>
<div class="headings">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <h2>Описание</h2>
  <p><a href="#">телефон</a>
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>&copy; copyright</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот для выравнивания по вертикальному центру:

```
 body {height:100%; position:relative;}
 headings {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 #либо translateY(- половина высоты блока в px)
 }
```

Для header:

```
 header {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 }
```

Для footer:

```
 footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 }
```

UPD: footer, header

Comment: Как вариант, можно еще реализовать на Javascript

Comment: вот, что получается в вашем решении.
https://jsfiddle.net/xdkrxtn1/1/
ну что вы - куда еще скрипты на такие операции навешивать

Answer (score 1):

Вот так наверно , если я что то не понял - напишите

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
header {
  background: blue;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
main p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}
footer {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <p>
      Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
    </p>
  </main>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: так а что вы собственно хотели сделать? зачем вы выдумали другую структуру и что в итоге хотели отобразить?

Comment: я вам показал центрирование блока который в центре , дальше я показал как прижать футер к низу , просто всё в одной вёрстке , в вашем случае - заголовок  описание и телефон вставить в центральный блок если всё остальное не нужно пропустить

Comment: ну, т.е. по сути - вот так, да? а зачем вы задавали `main` `padding-bottom` ? https://jsfiddle.net/o8fh51oa/

Comment: это для того что бы сам main не налазил на footer , да там видно это всё - одна из технологий прижатия футера